# Python Pandas: add missing row of two dataframe and keep the extra columns

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I would like to add the missing row dataframe df1 and keep the extra columns information

```
In [183]: df1
Out[183]:
           City       Country     Region
0       Chicago           US      N.America 
1  San Franciso           US      N.America 
2        Boston           US      N.America 
3        London           UK      Europe
4        Beijing          China   Asia  
5         Omaha           US      N.America


In [183]: df2
Out[183]:
           City          
0       Chicago            
1  San Franciso 
2        Sao Paulo       
3        Boston                 
4        London            
5        Beijing 
6        Tokyo             
7        Omaha
```

The desired result after the merge is

```
           City       Country     Region
0       Chicago           US      N.America 
1  San Franciso           US      N.America 
2     Sao Paulo           nan     nan
3        Boston           US      N.America 
4        London           UK      Europe
5        Beijing          China   Asia 
6         Tokyo           nan     nan
7         Omaha           US      N.America
```

I am trying with `pd.merge(df2, df1, on='City', how='outer')` but return keyerror.

Comment: The answer not necessary to use merge. As long as City in `df2` that not in `df1` add into while maintaining the columns data in df1

Comment: I think solution  `pd.merge(df2, df1, on='City', how='outer')` is good here. What are `df1.columns` and `df2.columns` ? Are there in both `City` column?

Comment: Or you need `pd.merge(df2, df1, on='City', how='left')` ?

Comment: both return keyeror on `City`. Is it important position of `City` columns. Either 1st column or 2nd column matters?

Comment: Not sure if undertand, what is `print (df1.columns)` and `print (df2.columns)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, using `pd.merge`, `left_join`,  your desired output:

```
merged = pd.merge(df2,df1,how='left',on='City')
print(merged)
             City Country     Region
0         Chicago      US  N.America
1  San Fransicsco     NaN        NaN
2       Sao Paolo     NaN        NaN
3          Boston      US  N.America
4          London      UK     Europe
5         Beijing   China       Asia
6           Tokyo     NaN        NaN
7           Omaha      US  N.America
```

If you want to use an `outer` join, you can get this result using the below code:

```
merged_outer = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='City', how='outer')

print(merged_outer)

             City Country     Region
0         Chicago      US  N.America
1  San Fransicsco     NaN        NaN
2       Sao Paolo     NaN        NaN
3          Boston      US  N.America
4          London      UK     Europe
5         Beijing   China       Asia
6           Tokyo     NaN        NaN
7           Omaha      US  N.America
8    San Franciso      US  N.America
```

DF1 & DF2 respectively:

```
df1
 
           City Country     Region
0       Chicago      US  N.America
1  San Franciso      US  N.America
2        Boston      US  N.America
3        London      UK     Europe
4       Beijing   China       Asia
5         Omaha      US  N.America


df2

             City
0         Chicago
1  San Fransicsco
2       Sao Paolo
3          Boston
4          London
5         Beijing
6           Tokyo
7           Omaha
```